# Meaning $P(X=Y)$.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

I am working on this measure theory problem. We have two RV's $X$ and $Y$ defined on the space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. We have some conditions, and need to prove as a result that that $\mathbb{P}(X=Y) = 0$. (I do not want to put the whole question on the internet, therefore the vague description).

However, my question is mostly, how do I interpret the $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)$?

Comment: It's the probability of the set of all outcomes on which $X$ and $Y$ are equal.

Comment: $P(X = Y)$ is the probability of the event $\{ \omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) = Y(\omega) \}$, i.e. the measure of the outcomes such that $X = Y$. Note that this event is measurable since it equals $(X-Y)^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: More generally, if $\sigma(X,Y,\dots)$ is a statement that makes sense when $X,Y,\dots$ are numbers, and if someone writes $P(\sigma(X,Y,\dots))$ where $X,Y,\dots$ are random variables on some probability space, the intended meaning is the probability of the event $\{\omega\in\Omega:\sigma(X(\omega),Y(\omega),\dots)\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an elaboration of what has already been written in the comments.

In measure-theoretic probability, events are the same thing as measurable subsets of the probability space $\Omega$, and the probability of an event is the same thing as the $\mathbb P$-measure of that measurable set. In this case, the event "$X=Y$" means "the subset of $\Omega$ consisting of $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$". Since $X$ and $Y$ are random variables (i.e., measurable functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$) we also have that $X-Y$ is a measurable function, and thus its zero set is a measurable subset of $\Omega$. The $\mathbb P$-measure of this set is what you are after:
$$
P(X=Y):=\mathbb P\Bigl(\bigl\{\omega\in\Omega\colon X(\omega)=Y(\omega)\bigr\}\Bigr).
$$

For example, if $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ and $\mathbb P$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $X,Y$ are the corresponding coordinate functions, then the event $X=Y$ consists of the diagonal subset $\{(t,t)\colon t\in[0,1]\}$ which has Lebesgue measure zero, hence $P(X=Y)=0$ in this case. It's not a bad picture to have in mind either, even when $X,Y$ are arbitrary non-atomic independent random variables.

Comment: Thanks! It is clear now.